# Can I scrape product title from store url?

Tags: python, google-sheets, web-scraping

Is it possible to scrape 1 product title from each ecommerce store url input that I provide?

For example, I input a list of shopify store domain url's and it provides an output of just one single product title from that store.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a minute to read [ask] and update your code with a few code examples/desired output.